# Mongodb .net client options, which one do you prefer? Why?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
* mongodb-csharp driver
* simple-mongodb driver
* NoRM
```

There are three mongodb clients for .net, all of them appears to have same numbers of followers.

As i am new to mongodb can't differentiate both by just looking features right now.

**If you are using any of this client provider can you please share your take on it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the recent git builds of 10gen's [mongo-csharp-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver). It was a bit too bleeding edge when I first started testing it, before the 0.5 public release, but its quite stable now.

Comment: I saw it after i posted this question and trying it for last few days. Looks promising. although i feel bad that these companies use this opensoure tools as ladder. They could have adopted one of this project.

Answer (score 2):

I am the lead developer of [MongoVUE](http://blog.mongovue.com) - a popular .NET based windows admin tool for MongoDB. MongoVUE uses mongodb-csharp (0.9 master). My experience with the driver has been very good - it is quite robust. It performs well in multi-threaded situations. The community and developers are active and resolution to problems can be found in a few hours even during weekends.

I am evaluating simple-mongodb and may migrate to it as it matures (bugs+speed mainly).

Regards,
Ishaan

Answer (score 0):

I like [samus](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) driver. It is stable, fast and has all features of MongoDB as i know. Read [this](http://deserialized.com/the-state-of-mongodb-and-csharp/) article;)